# Switch output to variable (String)

Tags: perl

I started programming with Perl and have a problem to put the output from a switch (Cisco) in a variable.

Example:

I want to send the command `show version` to the switch (`$easy->send_command("show version");`
and then put the response from switch in a string (not in another file).

After then I will search in the string to compare versions (I declare at begin a string (this is the other variable for comparing) for example `$version = "bootflash:cat4500-ipbasek9-mz.122-50.SG2.bin";`)

At the moment I don't now how I can put the output from the switch in a string after I send the command Show version to them.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and include the code you have already written. We can't tell you how to solve a problem we know nothing about. How are you sending that command to the switch?

Comment: It's almost certain that the response is *already* in a variable, as data doesn't usually get written to a file without you writing code to do so. You need to show your code to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the return character

```
$easy->send_command("show version\r");
```

Save the output

```
$version=$easy->exp_before;
```

Change this to a regex

```
if ( $version =~ m"bootflash:cat4500-ipbasek9-mz.122-50.SG2.bin" ) {...}
```

remember to do term len 0 before you start running commands